# Java Convert String yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss to timestamp of Canada/Eastern timezone

Tags: java, datetime, timestamp

I have to get DateTime with using TimeZone and then get Timestamp from that DateTime

My Code is give below :

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date dt = new Date();
String currentTime = formatter.format(dt);
System.out.println("currentTime>>>>" + currentTime);

DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Canada/Eastern"));
Date parsedDate = format.parse(currentTime);
System.out.println("parsedDate>>>>" + parsedDate);
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime());
System.out.println("timestamp>>>>>>" + timestamp);
```

Problem is that I am not getting right datetime of Canada/Eastern TimeZone in timestamp.

I am getting the below time

```
currentTime>>>>2016-11-09 15:17:09
parsedDate>>>>Thu Nov 10 01:47:09 IST 2016
timestamp>>>>>>2016-11-10 01:47:09.0

Indian time is correct : 2016-11-09 15:17:09
When I parse it to Canada/Eastern it shows : Thu Nov 10 01:47:09 IST 2016
```

But eastern canada time is `04:50:21 EST Wednesday, 9 November 2016`

I am using Java with Eclipse Mars 1.

Comment: Can you use Java **8** java.time.* API? Or are you stuck with Java < 8 ?

Comment: @Fildor I am using jdk1.8.0_45 and import java.sql.Timestamp, java.text.DateFormat, java.text.SimpleDateFormat, java.util.Date, java.util.TimeZone.

Comment: It is still a little bit unclear to me, what you expect in contrast to what you are getting ... Since you create java.sql.Timestamp - is this going to be inserted into a DB?

Comment: @Fildor I am getting wrong timestamp.

Comment: @Fildor I have simple requirement I have to get Timestamp of Canada/Eastern TimeZone datetime.

Comment: Yes, so what you get is 11/10 01:47 but you expect 11/09 04:50 , is that correct?

Comment: @Fildor Yes you right.

Comment: How do you come to that expectation?

Comment: I think that rather than viewing the time zone as an attribute of the timestamp, you should view it as an attribute of how that time stamp is displayed. I strongly believe that `parsedDate` gives you the correct point in time. I furthermore think @Fildor was correct in the first comment, that the new `java.time.*` API in Java 8 may give you more of what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.now()
       .atZone( ZoneId.of( "America/Toronto" ) )
```

No parsing! Do *not* parse to adjust time zone.

Avoid the troublesome old classes: `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`, `java.util.Date`, `java.util.TimeZone`.

## java.time

You are using troublesome old date-time classes, now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

### `Instant`

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
```

> 2016-11-10T04:52:02.586Z

### Time zone

You can adjust this `Instant` into a time zone by applying a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

**Do *not* parse as a way to adjust time zone!** perhaps you are conflating a date-time object with a string that might represent its value. A date-time object can generate a string, and can parse a string, but the string is always distinct and separate from the date-time object.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are not true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

Furthermore, your `Canada/Eastern` zone is actually just an alias for the real zone of [`America/Toronto`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Toronto).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Toronto" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z );
```

> 2016-11-09T23:52:02.586-05:00[America/Toronto]

You could adjust into India time as well.

```
ZoneId zKolkata = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" );
ZonedDateTime zdtKolkata = instant.atZone( zKolkata );
```

> 2016-11-10T10:22:02.586+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "instant: " + instant );
System.out.println( "zdt: " + zdt );
System.out.println( "zdtKolkata: " + zdtKolkata );
```

> instant: 2016-11-10T04:52:02.586Z
>
> zdt: 2016-11-09T23:52:02.586-05:00[America/Toronto]
>
> zdtKolkata: 2016-11-10T10:22:02.586+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]

See [live code in IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/HR5pfK).

### Database

By `Timestamp` I assume you meant [`java.sql.Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html). That class is now outmoded by the java.time classes, if you have a JDBC driver that complies with JDBC 4.2 or later. Just pass the `Instant` object to `PreparedStatement::setObject`. Fetch via `ResultSet::getObject`.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , instant );
```

If your JDBC driver does not comply, fall back to converting to `java.sql.Timestamp`. But minimize use of that class, only for talking to the database. Immediately convert back into java.time. Do not attempt business logic with `Timestamp`.

```
java.sql.Timestamp ts = java.sql.Timestamp.from( instant );
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts ***ThreeTen-Backport*** (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Timestamp is unique and same every where in all timezones, which is value of new Date() in millis. What you are looking for here is formatted time of given timestamp (dt in above example.).

```
Date dt = new Date();
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

System.out.println("IST time: " + format.format(dt));

format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Canada/Eastern"));

String parsedDate = format.format(dt);

System.out.println("Canada Time: " + parsedDate);
```

Output:
IST time: 2016-11-09 16:33:22
Canada Time: 2016-11-09 06:03:22

Answer (score 0):

You can set the TimeZone based on GMT. We know that Canada time is [GMT-5](https://greenwichmeantime.com/time-zone/usa/eastern-time/),
so you can get the current Canada time like this:

```
    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-5");
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(tz);
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.CANADA);

    dateFormat.setTimeZone(tz);

    System.out.println(dateFormat.format(c.getTime()));
```

Output: 2016-11-09 06:08:47

You need to explicitly use `DateFormat.setTimeZone()` to print the Date in the desired timezone.
If you don't do this, the `c.getTime()` result will be your zone current time.

Answer (score 0):

A `Timestamp` doesn't have a time zone in Java, it only represents a moment in time based on a number of milliseconds elapsed since a reference point, the epoch.

So it seems to me that you want your Timestamp to point to the current instant, which would be written very simply:

```
//with Java 8
Timestamp ts = Timestamp.from(Instant.now());

//or prior to Java 8:
Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(new Date().getTime());
```